# Alexa timer API not working when changing {continutewithskillname} to something else

Tags: api, timer, python-requests, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to call subsequent task once the timer's is over via y timer API call. Per the [doc](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/alexa-timers-api-reference.html), I have to similar formated code:

```
timer_request = {
    "duration": "PT10S",
    "timerLabel": "My Task Timer",
    "creationBehavior": {
        "displayExperience": {
            "visibility": "VISIBLE"
        }
    },
    "triggeringBehavior": {
        "operation": {
            "type": "LAUNCH_TASK",
            "textToConfirm": [{
                "locale": "en-US",
                "text": "Timer elapsed. Would you like to launch {continueWithSkillName}?"
            }],
            "task": {
                "name": "CountDown",
                "version": "1",
            }
        },
        "notificationConfig": {
            "playAudible": True
        }
    }
```

}
However, as soon as, I change the `{continueWithSkillName}`to any other name or simply take the brackets out, I run into `bad request error`. Does anybody why or what shall I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read farther down in the docs you linked, it says it's mandatory.

** {continueWithSkillName} is mandatory somewhere. This is replaced with "continue with ". **

While it appears you can move it within the string where it appears, it must be part of the string.

Comment: Nice catch & Thank you so much :)